# Mocking a inner function for testing in go

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

Say I have 2 Functions `func GetCar()` and `func PrintFormat()`. For obvious reasons, `PrintFormat` is not part of the interface.

Both the functions are tied to `car struct{}` via function receivers.

How can I test `GetCar` given I have a dependency on `func PrintFormat()`.

Is it possible to mock `func PrintFormat()` to output some arbitrary value during tests that I can work with ?

```
type Car interface {
   GetCar(id string)  
}

type car struct {
   name string
   data data 
   printFormat string
}

func (c *car) GetCar(id string) {
   info := c.printFormat(id)
   fmt.Println(info)
}

func (c *car) printFormat(id string) {
   return DoSomething(id, c.printFormat)
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to mock methods on concrete types. You could make printFormat a function field, which will make it mockable. Or introduce a printer interface type, interfaces are also mockable in Go. And that's about it, interfaces and function values (variables, fields), is what you can mock in Go.